# iTunes Connect: in-App mass import via Application Loader: unknown price tier error

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, application-loader

I've been wanting to create a series of in-app purchases for my app in iTunesConnect via the Application Loader. In theory, one can create a tab-delimited txt-file with the product-ids, price, etc. to masscreate in-app purchases.

Unfortunately, in practice, I cannot get it to work. My sample in-app purchase has a "Wholesale Price Tier" of 32 and when I try to import the data from the txt-file, the application loader gives me the error-message: "Unknown price tier: 32" (or something to that effect, the message I get is in German).

This seems to be an error in the application loader, for the program even complains when I try to import the unmodified AppMassImportTemplate.txt template that comes with the Application loader.

Similarly, the programm does not accept an "End Date" of "None", even though this the recommended entry in the [Application Loader User Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/resources/download/AppLoaderUserGuide/pdf). But this, I can get around by simply omitting the column "End Date", I cannot, however omit the column "Wholesale Price Tier".

Has anyone encountered this problem as well, and found a way around it?

Comment: I just tried it, and get the same error as you for price tiers. I use tiers like 2 and 3 but it complains about them. It says to use integers, so how can we even know which ones refer to Alternate Tier 3 etc? Well, since no tiers seem to work now..... I'll just go curse at Apple...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it turned out, all I had to do was to use an outdated version of the Application Loader. The current version is 3.1, and can be downloaded from the iTunesConnect website (Under "resources and help", and not - as is stated in the Application Loader User Guide - under "My Apps").

The download link is: https://itunesconnect.apple.com//apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.1.dmg (you need to be logged into iTunesConnect for this link to work)

This link location can simply modified to download an older version, e.g.:

- https://itunesconnect.apple.com//apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.0.dmg (this worked without a hitch for me)
- or change the "3.0" to "2.9" if you need an even older version)

Version 3.0 does not complain about the price tier, though it still doesn't accept "None" as a valid "End Date" - but as I said above, this column can be omitted altogether.

Comment: Apple support, btw., in typical Apple support fashion, told me to RTFM - yes, the manual whose template entries do not work in their program...

Comment: Still not fixed in version 3.3 :(

Comment: I've just reverted to 3.0 because of price tier complaints and it accepts End Date "None". I used download link from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300464/bulk-iap-loading-using-application-loader-price-tiers

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in Application Loader.

I am using verison 3.5 and problem is there..

I have downloaded 3.0 from [here](https://itunesconnect.apple.com//apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.0.dmg) and this fixed my problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot omit the column "End Date", as a workaround, change your system language to 'English' before starting Application Loader and change it back to your normal language after uploading the In-App Purchase items.