# Bulk IAP loading using Application Loader, price tiers

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I get this:

```
Row 1 has an unknown In-App purchase price tier: 2.
```

How can this be an unknown price tier? I tried a few different ones like 3 and 4 but no go.

Also, on a related issue, there seems to be no way of getting the current price tiers into the Application Loader (the drop down is very very empty), so I can't actually edit/set the price tier for an IAP even manually using the Application Loader interface. Is AL heavily bugged?

Comment: Did you managed to do something ? I have the same problem :/

Comment: No. Just hammer and click endlessly in the super slow iTunes connect interface. Well it was 15 minutes of hard work. There is a tool called Fastlane and possibly other similar that can automate some of these things, but unfortunately IAP items are not supported.

Answer (score 5):

After searching, I found that Application Loader 3.1 was bugged. Using Application Loader 3.0, I don't have the unknown price tier anymore.
[Download link here](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.0.dmg)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Application Loader 3.4 (in Xcode 7.2) still contains the same bug.

Answer (score 0):

Bumped into this issue, and was able to solve it using Excel.  Basically, when you open the file to edit in Excel, you need to re-save it using "UTF-16 Unicode Text (.txt)" format, and not other text formats.  This requirement was indicated in the documentation of Application Loader.

You will also need to check to make sure there are no extra spaces or quotes in front of values in the individual cells.

I had the same error as the original poster, but after using Excel to edit the file and re-save in "UTF-16 Unicode Text (.txt)" format, got it to work with Application Loader 3.4 just fine.